# timestamp in this format : '2022-03-17T19:38:48.331000Z'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, iso8601

I want to transform a date which has the following format "2022-03-17T19:38:48.331000Z"
in order to know if it would give me valuable information.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests, json
from pandas import json_normalize
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone
!pip3 install zulu

input: column_timestamp
id                              timestamp 
ed25291d0f5edd91615d154f243f82f9    2022-03-18T07:33:36.882000Z
e02c5db9e6f6fca078798c9b2d486a81    2022-03-18T07:33:36.945000Z
f8756b6af18c2fedd8a295040279aecc    2022-03-18T07:33:37.549000Z
...

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone
!pip3 install zulu


time = []
for i in range(505):
  dt = zulu.parse(column_timestamp["timestamp"][i])
  dt.format('% m/% d/% y % H:% M:% S % z')
  time.append(dt)
  i = +1

time_df = pd.DataFrame(time)
time_df
```

output:

```
    0
0   2022-03-18 07:33:36.882000+00:00
1   2022-03-18 07:33:36.945000+00:00
2   2022-03-18 07:33:37.549000+00:00
3   2022-03-18 07:33:37.550000+00:00
4   2022-03-18 07:33:37.552000+00:00
... ...
```

I want to know if it's correct and as well split this dataframe into different columns:

- Date
- Hour
- Minute
- Seconds

- And make sure if I'm doing the conversion correct:
  '2022-03-18T07:33:36.746000Z'

Comment: And now your question is which standard library module you can use for that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you need to parse and/or format: [python how do i make this json response timestamp to a datetime-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71519780/python-how-do-i-make-this-json-response-timestamp-to-a-datetime-format) good coding! ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: just use `pd.to_datetime` to parse your strings to datetime type; you have pretty common ISO format.